# Can I use relative path for image in SLD 1.1.0

Tags: geoserver, sld, file-path

Can I use relative path in the SLD 1.1.0? When validating it in geoserver, it said

```
Parsing failed for ExternalGraphic: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
```

SLD:

```
<se:PointSymbolizer>
      <se:Graphic>
       <se:ExternalGraphic>
         <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="images/mrtstation.png"/>
        <se:Format>image/png</se:Format>
       </se:ExternalGraphic>
       <se:Size>4</se:Size>
      </se:Graphic>
</se:PointSymbolizer>
```

Comment: That should work (it's relative to the styles directory) - try with ./ on the front.

Comment: Try Ian's suggestion, but it may well not be working, the SLD 1.1 parser is an entirely different code base (and not as complete and well maintained as the SLD 1.0 one)

Comment: Documentation shows an example about the syntax http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346001/geoserver-sld-styling-issue-with-external-graphics-and-attribute-rules).

In a nutshell, relative paths do not work. Use URL paths.